selecting a contour from multiple contours of same level
I'm Trying to obtain the contour at a given level, say 23 C from a time vs depth data of temperature. The contour 23 is overlaid onto the figure.
How do I isolate and select one single contour path from the lots of paths.

I Tried obtaining the vertices from path, but they are huge in number and I don't find any method to select just one of the paths.
    plt.contourf(ds.TIME1,ds.DEPTH,ds.temp,levels=(np.arange(50,450,40)),cmap="hot)
    contour = plt.contour(ds.TIME1,ds.DEPTH,ds.temp,levels=[23])
    paths = contour.get_paths()
    paths[0].vertices


Possibly you want contour.allsegs, but it is hard to advise without knowing what you are ultimately trying to do.

@RuthC That suggestion along with other documents worked like charms. I was stuck with get_paths and could go no further.

There is no need to get paths but a similar feature, it's called segments I suppose.
plt.contourf(ds.TIME1,ds.DEPTH,ds.temp,levels=(np.arange(50,450,40)),cmap="hot")
contour = plt.contour(ds.TIME1,ds.DEPTH,ds.temp,levels=[23])
contour.allsegs[0][1] # this will give all the x,y data points for segment, and so on for rest of the segments. 

